# PHP inner join categories

Tags: php, mysql

I got stuck on something with PHP., 
I am trying to JOIN two tables

```
$statement = $database->prepare("SELECT categories.name as category_name ,pages.name as page_name FROM categories INNER JOIN pages ON categories.name = pages.category");
$statement->execute();
$fetch = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$returnValues = '';
foreach($fetch as $item){
    if(isset($returnValue[$item->category_name]){
        array_push($returnValue[$item->category_name], $item->page_name);
    }else{
        $returnValue[$item->category_name][] = $item->page_name;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($returnValue);
```

Basically I want to get an array which got the category name and behind it all the pages that belongs to that category. now on this PHP code, I get plenty of array which everyone holds category name and one page.. and I can't sort it out , thanks.

Comment: I am not following... please post what you are getting and an example of what you are expecting.  I might be able to help with these 2 pieces of information.

Comment: Basically i get an array like this:
[0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Home // category name
            [name] => about us
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Home
            [name] => contact us
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Home
            [name] => example
        )
  
  I want it to be like this
  [name] = > array
  {
   [0] => about us
   [1] => contact us
   [2] => example
  }

Comment: I have added changes to your original code that should do what you want... again it is just rough code, may or may not need slight changes

Answer (score 1):

Alias the category name so that you can tell it apart from the page name.  This query will select the category name and all columns from table pages.

```
$statement = $database->prepare("SELECT categories.name AS category_name, pages.* FROM categories INNER JOIN pages ON categories.name = pages.category");
$statement->execute();
$fetch = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Group each row by category name.  Change $row['id'] to whatever you use as the primary ID for table pages.

```
$categoryPages = array();
foreach ( $fetch as $row ) {
    $categoryPages[$row['category_name']][$row['id']] = $row;
}
print_r($categoryPages);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is modifications to your original code, should basically do what you want, there might be some small syntax changes needed.

```
$statement = $database->prepare("SELECT categories.name as category_name ,pages.name as page_name FROM categories INNER JOIN pages ON categories.name = pages.category");
$statement->execute();
$fetch = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$returnValues = '';
foreach($fetch as $item){
    if(isset($returnValue[$item->category_name]){
        array_push($returnValue[$item->category_name], $item->page_name);
    }else{
        $returnValue[$item->category_name][] = $item->page_name;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($returnValue);
```

Something like this might work for you... I know it is not perfect and there are something thing missing in the query prepare, but it should be enough to get you going.

The compiled array should be formatted the way you want.

```
$statement = $database->prepare("SELECT categories.name FROM categories");
$statement->execute();
$fetch = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$compiled = '';
foreach($fetch as $category){
    $statement = $database->prepare("SELECT page.name FROM pages WHERE pages.category = $category");
    $statement->execute();
    $pages = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($pages as $page)
        array_push($compiled[$category], $page);
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($compiled);
```

Comment: Hey Lars, That's extacly what I did on the start. But I find it inefficent to make a loop for queries, That's why I have used an inner join , Can't solve this thing.

Comment: You will not be able to solve this with an Inner join, SQL does not work that way.  SQL just returns rows of data and nothing more, it will not format andy data into Array structures.  

The best you might be able to do is a sub select that formats the page names into a comma separated list as value 2 of the main select.

Comment: Any way to make it work inside php ? i don't want to loop queries